# Vector Building Footprint Resources - Tokyo

Tags: openstreetmap, vector, footprint

I typically know where to look for this data in the United States, but I'm at a loss when looking for building footprint shapefiles abroad. I thought I could find what I was looking for with Open Street Map data, but when I check out http://downloads.cloudmade.com/asia/eastern_asia/japan/tokyo#downloads_breadcrumbs I don't get the files I need. 
Anyone know other resources, either official or osm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can try downloading the [Japan OpenStreetMap data at Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/openstreetmap/asia/). You can choose between pbf, bz2 or zipped shapefiles. It should have the files you need.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for this, it had what I needed, though building footprint data is a little spotty in some neighborhoods.  Based on my conversations with Japanese planners about the inaccessibility of official data like this, I think this is probably the best I can do without a lot of paperwork.

Comment: Yeah. It can't be helped. The data is contributed by volunteers and there are just more volunteers in some areas ( usually the more populated ones ) than others. Good luck!